# How does PTS slave communicate with PTM file descriptor?

Tags: linux, pseudoterminal

1. The /dev/ptmx is UNIX 98 master **clone device** [Source](https://linux.die.net/man/7/pty)
2. When a process opens /dev/ptmx, it gets a **file descriptor** for a pseudoterminal master (PTM), and a pseudoterminal slave (PTS) device is created in the /dev/pts directory [Source](https://linux.die.net/man/4/ptmx). There are **no nodes** in the file system for master devices [Source](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19253-01/816-4855/termsub15-14/index.html).
3. Data written to the slave is presented on the master **descriptor** as input. Data written to the master is presented to the slave as input [Source](https://linux.die.net/man/4/ptmx).
4. In Unix and related computer operating systems, a file descriptor (FD, less frequently fildes) is an abstract indicator (handle) used to access a **file** or other input/output **resource**, such as a pipe or network socket [Source](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File_descriptor).

Conclusion:

1. /dev/ptmx is just kind of a "mold" to clone masters (file descriptor actually).
2. A pseudoterminal is a pair of virtual devices that provide a bidirectional communication. One end of the channel is a **file decriptor** (Master) and the other is a /dev/pts/n **device** (Slave).
3. There is no PTM device but only a file descriptor.
4. A file descriptor is used to access a **file** or **resource**.

Questions :

1. Where is located the PTM resource that the file descriptor handle?
2. Why do we call PTM master "device"? Since there is no entry in /dev for it.
3. Can a **modified** program like SSHD communicate with PTS directly without the PTM in the middle?

Comment: _When a process opens /dev/ptmx, it gets a file descriptor for a pseudoterminal slave (PTS) device created in the /dev/pts directory._ I only take away this part: "...master (PTM), and a pseudoterminal..." and it is correct.

Comment: As the code lines in my answer show, the **open("/dev/ptmx", ...)** line is just one step in the whole setup. This explains the subtle differences in our  descriptions.

Answer (score 4):

To understand how pseudoterminals work, you must consider them as an abstractization of real physical terminals. Nowadays, the most commonly seen physical terminals are the Linux virtual consoles, but back in the day real physical terminals were extremely common, and quite often the only part of a computer system a user saw in their daily work.

A real physical terminal has two very different sides (or "aspects" if you prefer):

- An "outer" side, where the user sits. This side has a keyboard, on which the user types characters, and a screen, on which the user sees computer output. In the pseudoterminal abstraction, this is the "master" side.
- An "inner" side, represented by a character device in the operating system. In the pseudoterminal abstraction, this is the "slave" side.

Between the "outer" side of a physical terminal and the "inner" character device used by programs to communicate with the user there is an entire series of processing; the terminal hardware itself updates the screen, the operating system may buffer user keystrokes and perform line editing etc.

[image: A Digital Equipment Corporation VT220 terminal]

*A Digital Equipment Corporation VT220 terminal. You are looking at its "front" side. With a pseudoterminal, this is represented by the "master" side. Picture from Wikimedia.*

1. Where are located the PTM resource that the file descriptor handle?

   They are located in kernel memory. When a process opens `/dev/ptmx` the kernel creates a new pseudoterminal consisting of a master side and a slave side; the master side belongs to the process which created it, so it does not need an entry in `/dev`; the slave side can be opened by any process which wants to communicate with a terminal, and thus needs an entry in `/dev`.
2. Why do we call PTM master "device"? Since there is no entry in /dev for it.

   We do not usually call it a device. We usually call it the master side of a pseudoterminal. But yes, it is much more like a character device than like a regular file. For example, the process which holds it cannot seek to a previous location -- it can only read new bytes or write new bytes.
3. Can a modified program like SSHD communicate with PTS directly without the PTM in the middle?

   Sshd does not communicate with the slave side of the pseudoterminal. Sshd holds the master side of the pseudoterminal; the slave side is used by the process (e.g., a shell) spawned by Sshd.

   Sshd works like this:

   - When a login request comes over the network and the user is authenticated, Sshd creates a new pseudoterminal; it holds the master side, and then spawn a process as required by the remote user (usually a shell), giving it the slave side of the pseudoterminal as standard input, standard output and standard error.
   - Characters received from the network are written by Sshd to the master side of the pseudoterminal; this emulates a user typing on the keyboard. The kernel processes (or not) this stream of characters. The process (e.g., a shell) which has the slave side of the pseudoterminal receives them as if it was communicating with a real terminal.
   - In between the master and the slave side there is the operating system kernel, which may perform some processing or not, depending on the status of the slave side. See [line discipline](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Line_discipline), and the manual pages of [`stty`](https://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/bionic/en/man1/stty.1.html)(1) and [`ioctl`](https://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/bionic/en/man2/ioctl.2.html)(2) (especially [as applied to terminals or the slave side of pseudoterminals](https://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/bionic/en/man2/ioctl_tty.2.html)).

```
 _______             ______       ______       ______       _____       ______
(       ) bytes in  |      |     |      |     |      |     |     |     | Bash |
(Network)---------->| Sshd |---->|Master|---->|  OS  |---->|Slave|---->|  Vi  |
(       )<----------|      |<----| PTY  |<----|kernel|<----| PTY |<----| Less |
(_______) bytes out |______|     |______|     |______|     |_____|     |______|

 _______           _____      ______      ______      _____      _____      _______
<       > Events  |     |    |      |    |      |    |     |    |     |    (       )
<  GUI  >-------->|Xterm|--->|Master|--->|  OS  |--->|Slave|--->| Ssh |--->(Network)
<       ><--------|     |<---| PTY  |<---|kernel|<---| PTY |<---|     |<---(       )
<_______> Drawing |_____|    |______|    |______|    |_____|    |_____|    (_______)
```

Comment: _They are located in kernel memory._ Is there any bash command to see it?

Comment: It small integer returned by `open`(2) is an index in the file table of the process. The entire file table is part of the kernel data structures which describe the process. I'm not sure what it is what you want to see.

Comment: _Characters received from the network are written by Sshd to the master side of the pseudoterminal._ How can a process (SSHD) write on file descriptor? As I know, the latter is used by the OS to access /dev/ptmx. Does it mean the SSHD writes on /dev/ptmx?

Comment: Sshd calls `open("/dev/ptmx", O_RDWR)`. It gets back a file descriptor. It then uses that file descriptor in calls to `read()` and `write()`. (You do know that a file descriptor is a small integer, and that the basic I/O system calls take that number as an argument, yes?) (And no, I'm not sure that Sshd opens `/dev/ptmx`; there are also other ways to [open the master side of a PTY](https://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/bionic/en/man7/pty.7.html). Many programs are written to use the older way, now called BSD-style PTYs.)

Comment: _You do know that a file descriptor is a small integer, and that the basic I/O system calls take that number as an argument, yes?_ Yes, but this small integer is used like "an alias" to access the real resource for reading and writing and not used to access the file descriptor itself. The latter is not the final resource.

Comment: I think there is some linguistic misunderstanding. When we say that a process reads from or writes to a file descriptor we mean that the process passes the file descriptor to `read()` or `write()` to access the underlying file / pipe / socket / stream / resource / communications channel.

Comment: That's why I am wondering whether this file, pipe, resource, etc. is the /dev/ptmx itself, because all we get after opening /dev/ptmx is a file descriptor.

Comment: When a process calls `open("/dev/ptmx")` the kernel creates a new master PTY and returns to the process a file descriptor which points to the newly created master PTY. `/dev/ptmx` itself is just a means to get this new resource from the kernel.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/99984/discussion-between-hisab-and-alexp).

Comment: So the terminal simulator provides the function which enable we roll-back previous lines?

Answer (score 0):

When I go to the top of this oracle link I find "preface":

> The STREAMS Programming Guide describes how to use STREAMS in
>   designing and implementing applications and STREAMS modules and
>   drivers, for architectures that conform to the **SolarisTM 7** DDI/DDK.

Solaris7 was from 1998-2010. And still this oracle/solaris link explains the setup in well commented C code:

```
fdm = open("/dev/ptmx", O_RDWR);  /* open master */
grantpt(fdm);                     /* change permission of slave */
unlockpt(fdm);                    /* unlock slave */
slavename = ptsname(fdm);         /* get name of slave */
fds = open(slavename, O_RDWR);    /* open slave */
```

Isolating these two lines, where a char dev is opened:

```
fdm = open("/dev/ptmx", O_RDWR);    /* open master */
fds = open( slavename,  O_RDWR);    /* open slave */
```

you see the symmetry...only difference is:

- fdm uses `string "/dev/ptmx"`
- fds uses `variable slavename` (containing a
  string like...?(bonus Q))

Of course the link is done here: `slavename = ptsname(fdm)`. In plain english: return name of slave belonging to fd returned by opening master device. Nobody said it is *trivial*.

Or is this a typo? No! It's ptsname() you need to find out which number/name (/dev/pts/8, /dev/pts/17, ...) the master side has assigned to the "ticket" you are holding (that fdm "handlle").

And `man ptsname`:

> The **ptsname()** function returns the name of the slave
>   pseudoterminal device *corresponding* to the master *referred to* by fd.

Twice you open a pseudo device to get a filedescriptor "fd_", but first fdm is "only" to get a fds. And then fds is used to r/w to that new slave side device.

Reminds of a hotel guest getting the key to his private room from a public room first.

---

But I would never have realized all this without that clarifying picture of a `real physical VT` of the original inventor of colored terminals supporting even sound.